# How to build a python wheel with a specific set of dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, vtk, python-wheel, pyvista

I am building a python wheel and encounter a problem by specifying the dependencies. The `install_requires` parameter of the `setup` method receives:

- `vtk_osmesa` and
- `pyvista`.

The problem above is, that `pyvista` has `vtk` as a dependency. However, since I would like to provide  a wheel for a headless machine with osmesa, `vtk_osmesa` is already a dependency, with a different set of libraries.

Is there a way specify that a certain dependency should not be installed with all its sub dependencies? I would gladly specify all required dependencies using a tool like [pip-compile](https://pip-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/pip-compile/).

Comment: It appears that `vtk` is not a dependency of `pyvista`, in fact, they explicitly exclude it for this very reason.  What am I missing? https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/blob/main/requirements.txt

Comment: @Razumov This is very good news, unfortunately, when installing `pyvista` in a virtual python environment, `vtk` is still being installed along with it (version 0.43.3). Even though it says on github that `vtk` is not in the requirements due to [pyproject.toml](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/blob/v0.43.3/pyproject.toml)?

Comment: @Razumov It's still listed as a dependency at https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/blob/f9296957fac144a270227d2900078c3404bb4c32/pyproject.toml#L36